# Creating a table a CSV and publishing the student results to a website?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Using the example CSV data below, I am trying to find a way to publish their testscores online in a nicely formatted, clear way...

#### Example CSV Data

```
School,Class,Data,Student,Data,Data,testscore
West,1B,Data,StudentA,Data,Data,55.42452912
West,1B,Data,StudentB,Data,Data,32.22219
West,2A,Data,StudentC,Data,Data,49.242
West,2A,Data,StudentD,Data,Data,23.42452912
East(LMK),2,Data,StudentE,Data,Data,13.42452912
North,B,Data,StudentF,Data,Data,15.42452912
North,B,Data,StudentG,Data,Data,93.42
```

For example, from the above data I would want to publish:

```
---------------------------------
West      | 1B | StudentA | 55.42
West      | 1B | StudentB | 32.22
---------------------------------
West      | 2A | StudentC | 9.24
West      | 2A | StudentD | 23.42
---------------------------------
East(LMK) | 2  | StudentE | 13.42
---------------------------------
North     | B  | StudentF | 15.42
North     | B  | StudentG | 93.42
---------------------------------
```

**Is there some sort of way I can put this into a simple bit of html, php, css...etc to make it nice to read on a website?**

Basically, it takes their school, class, studentname and testscore (to 2DP) and formats it in a table
Split up into sections based on Their School + Class as a unique identifier.

Does anyone know how best to acheive this, I realise it could be quite a complicated script.

Obviously, after it's created a file I will use the ftp lib to send it to the webserver

Thanks
- Hyflex

Comment: On what condition is the decision to write a `---------` row based on? From your example it seems like a line like this should be inserted if the `school` or `class`item is different from the row before. Is this correct?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Well, no because I have no idea where to start in terms of putting the data into some html or php...etc. I asked "how best" not "code this for me"

Comment: @SteinarLima Kind of, basically if you were to string consisting of their school + class `West 1B` for example that is the unique identifier to split by.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm feeling nice today, so I wrote you a snippet that should be useful. I didn't bother with inserting the horizontal lines, but you can probably achieve that yourself if it is important for you.

```
import csv

def get_html_table(data):
    s = '<table>\n'
    for row in data:
        s += '<tr>'
        for cell in row:
            s += r'<td>{}</td>'.format(cell)
        s += '</tr>\n'
    s += '</table>'
    return s

with open('testscore.txt') as ifile, open('output.html', 'wb') as ofile:
    data = []
    for row in list(csv.reader(ifile))[1:]:
        data.append([row[0], row[1], row[3], '{0:0.2f}'.format(float(row[6]))])
    ofile.write(get_html_table(data))
```

**testscore.txt:**

```
School,Class,Data,Student,Data,Data,testscore
West,1B,Data,StudentA,Data,Data,55.42452912
West,1B,Data,StudentB,Data,Data,32.22219
West,2A,Data,StudentC,Data,Data,49.242
West,2A,Data,StudentD,Data,Data,23.42452912
East(LMK),2,Data,StudentE,Data,Data,13.42452912
North,B,Data,StudentF,Data,Data,15.42452912
North,B,Data,StudentG,Data,Data,93.42
```

**output.html:**

```
<table>
<tr><td>West</td><td>1B</td><td>StudentA</td><td>55.42</td></tr>
<tr><td>West</td><td>1B</td><td>StudentB</td><td>32.22</td></tr>
<tr><td>West</td><td>2A</td><td>StudentC</td><td>49.24</td></tr>
<tr><td>West</td><td>2A</td><td>StudentD</td><td>23.42</td></tr>
<tr><td>East(LMK)</td><td>2</td><td>StudentE</td><td>13.42</td></tr>
<tr><td>North</td><td>B</td><td>StudentF</td><td>15.42</td></tr>
<tr><td>North</td><td>B</td><td>StudentG</td><td>93.42</td></tr>
</table>
```

Generally, you should use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read in your data, and something like [genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/) (check out [genshi.builder](http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/ApiDocs/genshi.builder)) to produce your html.

Comment: Interesting, any pointers how to construct a simple table?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used this module before. It might even be a bit of overkill.